# Javascript add js libraries by code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split my long JavaScript code into different libraries.

I'm trying to write a wrapper script that will load all my libraries:

```
//this file loads all the scripts to the page    
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fileName = getCurrentFileName();
    loadScript("scripts/pico/popups.js");
    loadScript("scripts/pico/effects.js");
    loadScript("scripts/pico/pico.js");
    loadScript("scripts/pico/facebook.js");
    if (fileName != null)
        loadScript("script/pico/" + fileName + ".js");
});    
/**
     * Load a script to the body element
     * @param name the name of script file.js
     */
function loadScript(name){
    // Adding the script tag to the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = name;
    // Fire the loading
    body.appendChild(script);
}    
/**
     * Get the current HTML file name
     * @returns {*} the name of the file or null
     */
function getCurrentFileName(){
    try {
        var fileName;
        fileName = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
        return fileName.split('.')[0];
    }
    catch (e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

but i think facebook.js is loaded before pico.js has finished loading - and these are functions from pico.js inside facebook.js..

how can i make sure the libraries will be loaded in the order i enter it ?

Comment: You would need to use the onreadystatechange handler to ensure that they are loaded in the order required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21246366/1959948

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/minify/ Combines, minifies, and caches JavaScript and CSS files on demand to speed up page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the onreadystatechange handler to ensure that they are loaded in the order required.

```
//this file loads all the scripts to the page

$(document).ready(function () {
    var fileName = getCurrentFileName();
    loadScript("scripts/pico/popups.js");
    loadScript("scripts/pico/effects.js");
    loadScript("scripts/pico/pico.js",function(){
        loadScript("scripts/pico/facebook.js");
        if (fileName != null) loadScript("script/pico/" + fileName + ".js");
    });
});

/**
 * Load a script to the body element
 * @param name the name of script file.js
 */
function loadScript(name,callback) {
    // Adding the script tag to the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState === "complete" && $.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback();
        }
    }
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = name;
    // Fire the loading
    body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Since jQuery is already included, it's even easier.

```
//this file loads all the scripts to the page

var fileName = getCurrentFileName();
$.getScript("scripts/pico/popups.js");
$.getScript("scripts/pico/effects.js");
$.getScript("scripts/pico/pico.js",function(){
    $.getScript("scripts/pico/facebook.js");
    if (fileName != null) $.getScript("script/pico/" + fileName + ".js");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider  using requirejs

http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/

Here is sample version:

1. You can download Require [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs).
2. The sample is based on this folder structure :

   public

   - index.html
   - scripts

     - app.js
     - lib

       **  jquery-1.10.2.js

       ** require.js

3 . From Code:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Sample Test</title>
<script src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>  <!-- downloaded from link provide above-->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script></head>
<body><h1>My Sample Project</h1><div id="someDiv"></div></body></html>
```

**application configuration app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',

    paths: {
        app: 'app',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.10.2' //your libraries/modules definitions
    }
});

// Start the main app logic. loading jquery module
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $(document).on('ready',function(){
            $('#someDiv').html('Hello World');
        });
 });
```

Comment: There is of course some options available using JQUERY http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Dependency Management". There are several solutions out there for this problem.

One big one is RequireJS: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

See also:

- [JavaScript dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202606/javascript-dependency-management)
- [Autoloading Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246224/autoloading-javascript/21246366#21246366)